# Emacs Prelude `whitespace-empty-at-eob-regexp` allow single empty line

Tags: regex, emacs, emacs-prelude

On saving a file, whitespace-cleanup does a nice job of cleaning up whitespace:

https://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/05/16/whitespace-cleanup/

However, I would like to be able to leave a blank line at the end of buffer, either globally or add a hook for different modes.

I think if I edit this `whitespace-empty-at-eob-regexp` I should be able to do it?

whitespace-empty-at-eob-regexp’s value is `"^\\([    ]+\\)\\'"`

So I thought I could just add a `\n` but this does not achieve what I want:

`"^\\([    ]+\\n\)\\'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `whitespace-empty-at-eob-regexp` is `"^\\([ \t\n]+\\)\\'"` actually.

I you want to leave a blank line at the end of buffer. Try:

```lisp
(setq whitespace-empty-at-eob-regexp "^[ \t\n]\\([ \t\n]+\\)\\'")

;; Tips: you can use xr and rx to play with regex more relaxed in emacs.
;; (xr "^[ \t\n]\\([ \t\n]+\\)\\'")
;; (seq bol
;;      (any "\t\n ")
;;      (group
;;       (one-or-more
;;        (any "\t\n ")))
;;      eos)
```